# Why `GroebnerBasis` fails to reduce a system to one scalar equation, when I can almost do it by hand?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, groebner-bases

I have a system of five equations (Behn's model of CD4+T/APC interaction). The last four yield rational solutions in `x1`, so I can plug these in the first equation to reduce the system to a scalar equation. But there are 4 distinct rational solutions of 2-3-4-5, so I only showed the degree of the result for one of them:

```
eqs = {α - x1 (c1 y2 + b1 y3 + βN) - 
   x1 x5 (x4 κ + x2/(1 + x3 μ2) + 
      x3 ϕ), -x2 β1 + (
   x1 x2 x5 γ1)/((1 + x3 μ2) (1 + 
      x4 μr)), -x3 β2 + (
   x1 x5 γ1 ϕ)/((1 + (x2 μ1)/(1 + x3 μ2)) (1 + 
      x4 μr)), -x4 βr + 
   x1 x4 x5 γ1 κ, λ + 
   x5 (y5 β - γ2 - x4 μ)}; 

X = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5};   
el = {2, 3, 4, 5}; 
cx = Solve[Thread[eqs[[el]] == 0], X[[el]]] // FullSimplify;
Print[el, " equations have ", Length[cx], " solutions:"]
cx
cof = CoefficientList[Numerator[Together[eqs[[1]] /. cx[[2]]]], x1];
Print["scalar pol has degree ", Length[cof] - 1]
```

All this takes 0 time. I also tried the elimination via `GroebnerBasis`

```
    in = {1}; 
    par = Complement[Variables[eqs], X]
    X[[in]]
    X[[el]]
    Timing[pol = 
       GroebnerBasis[Numerator[Together[eqs]], Join[X[[in]], par], 
        X[[el]]];]
```

and this seems to take forever. I imagine that it should take a bit longer because maybe it must get the product of the four scalar polynomials corresponding to the four solutions, but more than 10 minutes suggests that something bad happened (in fact, I had other experiments when this Groebner elimination seemed to fail, leaving me puzzled).

Comment: There could be a few reasons for this to be slow. Making the parameters into variables and, moreover, placing them at the top of the (implied) lexicographic ordering is one such. Not using Numerator[Together[…]] on them is another; GroebnerBasis instead must create new variables and polynomials to deal with denominators. Solve also has the luxury of treating the parameters as coefficients instead of variables, and this can give an advantage to how it uses GroebnerBasis.

Comment: Did you verify the result of `Solve`? The `Solve` command allows non-equivalent transformations.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: Dear Daniel, thanks, I was hoping you'd offer advice. But... 1) It's actually probably lost in hyperspace, rather than slow, since it's been running now for two hours. 2) I switched the order of the parameters ,  and added Numerator[Together[…]], it's still running for now.  3) If I understand your last remark,  you are suggesting that if know in which order it's easier to eliminate, we may beat the  Groebner algorithm?

Comment: @user64494 Indeed, there may be more solutions than 4, maybe 6. This is what I got by solving after adding Numerator[Together[…]], and this left me quite puzzled.  So, maybe Groebner needs to deal with 6, or even more scalar polynomials to piece together

Comment: @Domen, how did you arrange that greek letters appear in the question, instead of the Mathematica code I had put?

Comment: @florin, I use [Editor buttons for MMA.SE](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1044/75628).

Comment: Strangely enough, handling the last four equations in the last four variables is fast relative to working with all five in one go. Here is a question: What is the end goal, that is, the  problem you need to solve? Is it to get a univariate polynomial in one of the variables? Is it to count the size of the generic solution set? Depending on what's wanted, there may be easier ways to go about it.

Comment: The final task is to find  the set of parameters where all solutions are non-negative, and to divide it by the number of stricly   positive solutions (but adding positivity constraints to the equalities, in Reduce, seems to increase execution times). But to get a univariate polynomial in one of the variables is also interesting, because this is what people in non-negative dynamical systems often do. Reduce to one variable, and then use things like Descartes rule. Thanks for rendering clear for me what are the keywords of my problem:)